# What are the differences between Heap File Organization and Sequential File Organization (Pile Method)

Tags: storage, dbms, data-pages

I was learning about File Organization in DBMS, but i found that the Heap File Organization and Sequential File Organization (Pile Method) have the same definition (or maybe i couldn't find any differences between them).

Heap File:

> In heap file organization, the records are inserted at the file's end. When the records are inserted, it doesn't require the sorting and ordering of records.

Sequential File Organization (Pile Method) :

> the record will be inserted in the order in which they are inserted into tables, so When a new record is inserted, it is placed at the end of the file.

So any one might explain it to me?

Comment: Can you please link where you got those definitions from?

Comment: @J.D.
sequential-file-organization:
https://www.tutorialcup.com/dbms/sequential-file-organization.htm

Heap:
https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-heap-file-organization